# I cannot query or check for existing tables in tempdb

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a strange problem where I cannot query the tempdb to check what tables exists using the following code:

```
select * from tempdb.sys.tables
where name = OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID('##NewTableX'))
```

Even just selecting everything from `tempdb.sys.tables` doesn't work using:

```
select * from tempdb.sys.tables
```

I also cannot check for an existing table in the tempdb using the following code:

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##NewTableX') IS NOT NULL
    begin
        DROP TABLE ##NewTableX
    end
```

Every time I try to execute any code to do with the tempdb the query runs for ever in SQL Server Management Studio.

If I create a brand new temporary table using insert into code that works

```
select * into ##NewTableY from OPENQUERY(QBREMOTE,''sp_report ProfitAndLossByJob show Amount_Title, Text, Label, Amount parameters DateFrom = {d''''''2021-01-01''''''}, DateTo = {d''''''2021-12-30''''''}, EntityFilterFullNameWithChildren="'+REPLACE('ALL','''','''''')+'", SummarizeColumnsBy = "TotalOnly"'')'
```

Can anyone shed any light on what might be happening with the tempdb and why I cannot query it?

Comment: Please share the error you are facing.

Comment: There is no error it just carries on executing forever

Comment: Probably an open transaction holding a lock on the tempdb metadata. You need to check for blocking and what you are blocked by

Comment: I have had a look at the blocking and there are three spid's blocking the tempdb. I have tried to kill the processes, It sais it has killed them but when I do sp_who2 they are still there and it still has blocked by against them. Is the only solution to this to restart the Sql server or is there a better way?

Comment: probably some lock preventing the query to be completed, you can use "WITH(NOLOCK)" to read without waiting for the lock. you just need to put it next to the table you're querying, like this: "FROM tableName WITH (NOLOCK)"

Comment: What are the values under `status` and `command` returned by `sp_who2`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find what was blocking it but nothing worked. In the end I had to restart the Sql server, which I was trying to avoid doing. This solved my problem